# Add a product collection to customer entity type

Tags: product, attributes, customer, collection

I would like to allow a logged in user to select his or her favorite products. This list should be maintained from a new account page to be created following Alan Storm his article:  http://alanstorm.com/magento_create_customer_page.

I have found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426639 which (among others) shows how to add an attribute to a customer type.

What I would like to know is how I can add a product collection attribute type to a customer account.

Comment: wishlist products doesn't fulfill your requirement?

Comment: Unfortunately not, a user should both be able to keep a list of products that he wants (or considers) to buy as well as show a list of products he recommends to other users.

Comment: How user recommends products to other users via email to a friend link or by other way?

Comment: Users can view the producs recommended by another user. I will build a public "profile" page for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but I would like to make a suggestion.

I think what you want to do is basically mimic the wishlist functionality, but have the option to add to a wishlist OR "favorite" an item. I would suggest creating a table(s) that holds the customer id along with the product id and then loading your product collections based on the relevant data. Take a look at the wishlist table to get an idea where to start. (wishlist, wishlist_item, wishlist_item_option)

Comment: Well, it is a bit different in the form that this group of customers can recommend products while normal customers cannot. But still it is a starting point.

Comment: But if anyone has some example code or a link to a tutorial on how to add a product collection to a customer account (or something else that's not a product) then I would be very grateful!